# Someone has deleted my master branch on origin. How to recover the branch and find the person responsible

Tags: git, git-branch

Someone from my team has deleted the master branch unintentionally from the origin. I want to retrieve the master branch in the same state as it was before deletion and want to know who was the person responsible.

I have tried running the git -reflogs and also tried to check the insight option available on the github.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just push the latest master commit back to master:

```
git push [commit hash]:refs/heads/master
```

If you have a Build Server in your project and it's triggered on each push to master, then you can figure out the right commit hash. Though you'll also need to find someone who has this commit (again - Build Server would tell you).

Git can't tell you who did this. Only if Git Server logs this information - then you can figure this out. I don't know of such functionality on github.com.

Comment: Thanks, Stanislav. This restored the master branch on the origin with all the history.